# Change entry point with gnu linker

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, ld

I have an assembly file with a `_start` label as the first thing in the `.text` segment. I would like this label to be the entry point of my application.

Whenever I pass this file together with another file that have a function called `main`, that `main` function ends up being the entry point of my application no matter what.

I am using the GNU linker and have tried the `-e _start` flag, along with changing the input file order. As long as there exist a `main` function, it will become the entry point.. If I rename the `main` function, it works fine and my `_start` label becomes the entry point.

EDIT: Seems like it is because of `-O2` flag to the compiler.

**as.s**

```
.text
.global  _start
_start:
jmp main
```

**main.c**

```
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

**Compile**

```
gcc -O2 -c as.s -o as.o
gcc -O2 -c main.c -o main.o
ld -e _start as.o main.o -o test
```

**Output**

```
00000000004000b0 <main>:
  4000b0:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  4000b2:   c3                      retq   

00000000004000b3 <_start>:
  4000b3:   e9 f8 ff ff ff          jmpq   4000b0 <main>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You forgot to post any proof, also no version or environment information and no [mcve]. I have tested, it works fine.

Comment: You do realize that just because `main` comes before `_start`, it's not the entry point, right? The entry point is given in an ELF header field.

Comment: Kind of. I need the _start label to be at the start of the executable area anyhow. It seems to work fine with `-O1` and `-O0` though.

Comment: Do you need it at the beginning of the file because you are loading this with a bootloader and you intend to JMP/CALL to it. Requiring a particular label like `_start` to be at a specific place suggests to me there is more to this than meets the eye.

Comment: If I want a particular function to be the first thing in an executable I'd place it into its own section and create a linker script that locates that section at the start.

Comment: So, you asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears your question really is *How can I place a particular function before all others in the generated executable?*

First thing is that doing this only has value in certain circumstances. An *ELF* executable has the entry point encoded in the *ELF* header. The placement of the entry point in the executable isn't relevant.

One special circumstance is a non-mulitboot compatible kernel where a custom bootloader loads a kernel that was generated by *GCC* and converted to binary output. Looking through your question history suggests that bootloader / kernel development might be a possibility for your requirement.

---

When using *GCC* you can't assume that the generated code will be in the order you want. As you have found out options (like optimizations) may reorder the functions relative to each other or eliminate some altogether.

One way to put a function first in an *ELF* executable is to place it into its own section and then create a linker script to position that section first. An example linker script `link.ld` that should work with *C* would be:

```
/*OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386");*/
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-x86-64");

ENTRY(_start);

SECTIONS
{
    /* This should be your memory offset (VMA) where the code and data
     * will be loaded. In Linux this is 0x400000, multiboot loader is
     * 0x100000 etc */
    . = 0x400000;

    /* Place special section .text.prologue before everything else */
    .text : {
        *(.text.prologue);
        *(.text*);
    }

    /* Output the data sections */
    .data : {
        *(.data*);
    }

    .rodata : {
        *(.rodata*);
    }

    /* The BSS section for uniitialized data */
    .bss : {
        __bss_start = .;
        *(COMMON);
        *(.bss);
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __bss_end = .;
    }

    /* Size of the BSS section in case it is needed */
    __bss_size = ((__bss_end)-(__bss_start));

    /* Remove the note that may be placed before the code by LD */
    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.note.gnu.build-id);
    }
}
```

This script explicitly places whatever is in the section `.text.prologue` before any other code. We just need to place `_start` into that section. Your `as.s` file could be modified to do this:

```
.global  _start

# Start a special section called .text.prologue making it
# allocatable and executable
.section .text.prologue, "ax"

_start:
jmp main

.text
# All other regular code in the normal .text section
```

You'd compile, assemble and link them like this:

```
gcc -O2 -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -O2 -c as.s -o as.o
ld -Tlink.ld main.o as.o -o test
```

An `objdump -D test` should show the function `_start` before `main`:

```
test:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00400000 <_start>:
  400000:       e9 0b 00 00 00          jmp    400010 <main>
  400005:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%eax,%eax,1)
  40000c:       00 00 00
  40000f:       90                      nop

00400010 <main>:
  400010:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400012:       c3                      ret
```