# Raw binary entry point

Tags: c, linker, ld, osdev, lld

I'm having issues in specifying the entry point for my hobby OS kernel.

There is a simple bootloader that loads the kernel code to `0x6400000` address and jumps there.

Then I have this linker command which outputs kernel with the starting address:

```
ld --Ttext 0x6400000 -m elf_i386 --oformat binary -e kmain main.o -o main.bin
```

There's `main.cc` with the entry point function:

```
void kmain() { // ... }
```

Everything works fine as long as `kmain()` is the very first defined function.
If it's not:

```
void do_smth() { // ... }

void kmain() 
{
    do_smth();
}
```

Then `ld` (and `lld`) ignores the `-e kmain` argument, and makes the `do_smth()` an entry point.

How could I force `ld` to make `kmain()` an entry point with an address of `0x6400000`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCC: how to tell GCC to put the 'main' function at the start of the .text section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470666/gcc-how-to-tell-gcc-to-put-the-main-function-at-the-start-of-the-text-sectio)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change entry point with gnu linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301831/change-entry-point-with-gnu-linker)

Comment: The ELF entry point will be correctly set to the symbol kmain. But you specified _binary_ as output format! So you do not have an ELF header any more specifying kmain as entry. What you really want is probably to have kmain at the very beginning of your binary, correct?

Comment: @Ctx yes, that's the case.

Comment: Is the entry point parameter completely unused when linking to binary format?

Comment: @Pyjong yes, from what I've observed, it's unused.

Comment: @PovilasB Ok, thanks!